# String Replace not changing the String

Tags: python, string

I try to replace some braces with ids to braces with a name and id like this `{20}` to `{sensor_20}`

I have try this:

```
print('{{{}}}'.format(sensor.id))
struct.expression.replace('{{{}}}'.format(sensor.id), '{{sensor_{}}}'.format(sensor.id))
print(struct.expression)
```

But in terminal says:

```
{19} #String to replace
{19}+{20} #How string is in final
{20} #String to replace
{19}+{20} #How string is in final
```

Comment: The string `.replace()` method returns a new string; it does not modify the existing string.  You are calling `.replace()` without capturing the return value.

Comment: struct.expression = struct.expression.replace(f'{{{sensor.id}}}', f'{{sensor_{sensor.id}}}')

Comment: Strings are immutable in python, like most languages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) says:

> **Return** a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the
>   first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.

The string itself is not modified.

Comment: As an addendum to this, strings in Python are immutable, so it's not possible to modify then by *any* means.